# solidity start to complie button is not working

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to learn solidity and have copy and pasted code from the tutorial i'm working through into the remix browser IDE. I'm having trouble understanding how to test the contract.

Can someone please explain what i would need to do to test this code. I'm thinking i should be able to enter name and dna into the _createZombie function (somewhere in the right side panel) and then look at the Zombie struct to see that it has updated.

I've attached an image of the right side panel after i've selected 'start to compile'.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract ZombieFactory {

uint dnaDigits = 16;
uint dnaModulus = 10 ** dnaDigits;

struct Zombie {
    string name;
    uint dna;
}

Zombie[] public zombies;

function _createZombie(string _name, uint _dna) private {
    zombies.push(Zombie(_name, _dna));
}

// start here

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The compilation was successful, this is what that green box means. After the code is compiled you can switch over to the run tab of the right panel in order to deploy your contract and test it.